# How to create multiple class with same function

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

So for some reason, I have to create multiple classes.
Just like this code

```
class Myclass1:
    do_x

class Myclass2:
    do_x

class Myclass3:
    do_x
```

Currently, I can do that by copying **do_x** over and over. However it seems not effective. Any better idea?

Comment: Have you heard of inheritance? You can make an abstract base class with whatever common methods and inherit from that  https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html

Comment: What you are looking for is [inheritance](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is inheritance.

```
class Myclass:
    def do_x(self):
        pass

class My_child(Myclass):
    def do_x(self):
        print("I am the chile class")

class My_2nd_child(Myclass):
    def do_x(self):
        print("I am the 2nd child")
```

The base class in this case has a stub for method do_x.

The child classes override that method to implement their own behaviors.

Inheritance is mostly useful for code reuse (DRY principle)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with the answer given by @Reblochon Masque...
There is another advantages here using `super` method is to execute child class method along with parent method.

```
  class Myclass(object):
    def do_x(self):
       print 'In parent Class'

  class Myfirstchild(Myclass):
    def do_x(self):
      print 'In child class';
      super(Myfirstchild, self).do_x()
```

Here the output/result would be

```
   In child class
   In parent Class
```